# Float right is not working with my Wordpress Mantra theme

Tags: css, wordpress, html-table, css-float

I need to place a table in the right corner of a page and text wrap around the table. I used the following codes.

```
.floater {
margin: 5px;
float: right;
}
.floater td {
padding: 2px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

```
<table class="floater">
*--- table---*
</table>
<p>text</p>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/es7t7xyo/
It is working well with the all the editor and not working while updating in my website. I am using Wordpress Mantra Theme.

Comment: Then post your code, which is not working.

Comment: Above what I have posted is not working with my website in the browser. While running the same code in editor or jsfiddle, it is working fine and working in the actual website page. That is my problem.

Comment: Assign specific width to your table, it will work

Answer (score 0):

You should define a width of your table like:

```css
.floater {
    margin: 5px;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
.floater td {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="floater">
    <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td></tr>
    <tr><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td></tr>
</table>
<p>Objectively matrix extensive manufactured products without cost effective ROI. Conveniently seize competitive expertise vis-a-vis standardized action items. Distinctively administrate scalable leadership after world-class process improvements.</p>
<p>Progressively utilize adaptive deliverables before open-source manufactured products. Appropriately transition innovative metrics for optimal methodologies. Assertively customize alternative customer service without client-focused web-readiness.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not working with my website. Here is the link. [link]http://eduprofessor.com/trail/